# angular 2.0 ngClass is not updated on timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-class

I'm using Angular 2.0 beta 15.

Initially I was experiencing this problem while developing an app. Then I decided to try the simplest possible case to reproduce it. See the code below

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [ngClass]="{'red-heading':isAlertOn, 'blue-heading':!isAlertOn}">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  isAlertOn:boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.isAlertOn = false;
  }

  (function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("in here");
      this.isAlertOn = true;
    },2000);
  })();
}
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oro6VHGiFMm3wesCfzyb?p=preview)

Since I'm using animations in my application I want to trigget class changing with a delay. In order to do that I'm using setTimeout.

I've read that in general all the changes are handled by NgZone manually (for some older alpha version I think). Right now those changes should be handled automatically. Either I'm missing something (still new in angular 2.0) or there might be a different approach.

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Updating classes dynamicaly can be achieved using the following syntax: `<div [class.my-class]="isClassVisible">`. It behaves like a two data bind `ng-class` from angular 1. Check this tutorial: [Learning Angular 2: Conditionally add styles to an element](http://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---------------------------------------------New Updates 2016-04-26 15:28-------------------------------------------

Ok I just figure out the way using CSS animation:

in the css do this:

```
@keyframes blueToRed{
  0% {color: blue}
  100% {color:red;}
}

.blue-to-red-heading {
  animation-name: blueToRed;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  /*animation-delay:2s; */ /*uncomment this for delays*/
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Then in app.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [ngClass]="{'blue-to-red-heading':isAlertOn}">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  isAlertOn:boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.isAlertOn = true;
  }
}
```

--------------------------------------------------Original Answer-------------------------------------------------------------
I think you got a great question.

I cannot figure out why exactly, but the problem lies in the immediate function.

Once you declare your function without running it immediately on the declaration.  It works.

And yes another thing: the setTimeout seems to mess up the "this"...

What i did on the app.ts:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [ngClass]="{'red-heading':isAlertOn, 'blue-heading':!isAlertOn}">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  isAlertOn:boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2';
    this.isAlertOn = false;
    this.setAlert();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   // this.setAlert(); //this works the same way
  }

  setAlert(){ 
    let component = this;

    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("in here");
      component.isAlertOn = true;
    },2000);
  };

}
```

Comment: I updated the plnkr not to use self-invoking function but to execute the time on click. This is the closest representation to what I have. The setTimeout is executed once I press a button.

Comment: I guess that should be fine too

Comment: You are executing it in the constructor. Bind it to click event.

Comment: You can put it into ngOnInit() also, which i think is cleaner.  I am thinking of using CSS animation to do it.  Later i will put some updates.  Can use as reference as well

Comment: You , my friend, are an awesome guy :).
I guess the problem is from 'this' for sure.

Comment: Do you know how to easily implement a RedToBlue to get back to normal smoothly when the class is removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with SCSS as well, no need for JS:

```
@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

@for $i from 0 through 20 {
  $duration: 1s + $i;

  .highlight-#{$i} {
    animation-name: highlight;
    animation-duration: $duration;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
}
```

and just add the corresponding highlight-1, 2, 3, etc classes.